# Data not returned from REST datasource in Apollo server for graphQL

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I am trying out the basic implementation for Apollo server for GraphQL with my REST API calls as Data Sources. I do not see any data returned from the same even though there is data returned when I call the API separately. Can anyone help figure out what could be going wrong?

PS: I have CORS enabled on my API so not sure if I am passing that too correctly. I do not have any idea how to figure out what URL this is calling.

My sample code below:

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server');

const { RESTDataSource } = require('apollo-datasource-rest');

class Contact extends RESTDataSource {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/objects/';
  }

  async getContactById(id) {
    return this.get(`contact/${id}`);
  }

  async getAllContacts() {
    const data = await this.get(`contact`);
    return data.results;
  }

  // an example making an HTTP PUT request
  async newContact(contact) {
    return this.put(
      'contact', // path
      contact, // request body
    );
  }
};

// Type definitions define the "shape" of your data and specify
// which ways the data can be fetched from the GraphQL server.
const typeDefs = gql`
  # Comments in GraphQL are defined with the hash (#) symbol.

  type Query {
    allContacts: [Contact]
    contactById(id: ID): Contact
  }

  type Contact {
    id: ID
    contact_name: String
  }
`;

// Resolvers define the technique for fetching the types in the
// schema.  
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    contactById: async (_source, { id }, { dataSources }) => {
      return dataSources.contact.getContactById(id);
    },
    allContacts: async (_source, _args, { dataSources }) => {
      return dataSources.contact.getAllContacts();
    },
  },
};

// In the most basic sense, the ApolloServer can be started
// by passing type definitions (typeDefs) and the resolvers
// responsible for fetching the data for those types.
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  dataSources: () => {
    return {
      contact : new Contact(),
    };
  },
  cors : true,
});

// This `listen` method launches a web-server.  Existing apps
// can utilize middleware options, which we'll discuss later.
server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

Below is the request and response from the GraphQL playground:

```
query {
  contactById (id : 5) {
    id
    contact_name
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "contactById": {
      "id": null,
      "contact_name": null
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: does the structure of your REST response match the structure of your GQL type?

Comment: No. It doesn't match the schema. However, field nes are the same. Does the response need to match in all ways?

Comment: if the structure matches, Apollo will automatically populate it. if not, one option is to write something along the lines of adapters.

Comment: that's what the idea behind a resolver is though, each resolver on a type should do this "adapting" in its code. but yeah having a matching structure is really easy. if you do ever go down that root though, always match the GQL structure to REST rather than vice versa, if GQL is the end-goal